Meshplot isn't working because jupyter-threejs isn't registered
When trying to plot my pointcloud using meshplot in jupyter notebook in VSCode, I get a javascript error telling me pythreejs isn't registered. I get the following errorlog:
[Open Browser Console for more detailed log - Double click to close this message]
Failed to load model class 'RendererModel' from module 'jupyter-threejs' 
Error: No version of module jupyter-threejs is registered at ph.loadClass (https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/c%3A/Users/ruben/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers-1.0.19/out/node_modules/%40vscode/jupyter-ipywidgets8/dist/ipywidgets.js:2:4099813) 
at ph.loadClass (https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/c%3A/Users/ruben/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers-1.0.19/out/node_modules/%40vscode/jupyter-ipywidgets8/dist/ipywidgets.js:2:4403287) 
at ph.loadModelClass (https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/c%3A/Users/ruben/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers-1.0.19/out/node_modules/%40vscode/jupyter-ipywidgets8/dist/ipywidgets.js:2:4097773) 
at ph._make_model (https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/c%3A/Users/ruben/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers-1.0.19/out/node_modules/%40vscode/jupyter-ipywidgets8/dist/ipywidgets.js:2:4094616) 
at ph.new_model (https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/c%3A/Users/ruben/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers-1.0.19/out/node_modules/%40vscode/jupyter-ipywidgets8/dist/ipywidgets.js:2:4092246) 
at ph.handle_comm_open (https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/c%3A/Users/ruben/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers-1.0.19/out/node_modules/%40vscode/jupyter-ipywidgets8/dist/ipywidgets.js:2:4091039) 
at https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/c%3A/Users/ruben/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers-1.0.19/out/node_modules/%40vscode/jupyter-ipywidgets8/dist/ipywidgets.js:2:4402511 
at n._handleCommOpen (https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/c%3A/Users/ruben/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.8.0-win32-x64/dist/webviews/webview-side/ipywidgetsKernel/ipywidgetsKernel.js:3:80955) 
at async n._handleMessage (https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/c%3A/Users/ruben/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.8.0-win32-x64/dist/webviews/webview-side/ipywidgetsKernel/ipywidgetsKernel.js:3:82830)

I have the following package versions: pythreejs=2.4.2 and meshplot=0.4.0. Does someone know how I can fix this?
I've tried installing different combinations of the meshplot and pythreejs libraries, but the error kept occuring. The problem arised without a specific cause that I could locate.

I currently solved it by redoing my conda environment installation, but that is not a clarification for the occurance of the errorlog. I have the following packages installed: meshplot=0.4.0=pyhd3deb0d_2, pythreejs=2.4.2=pyh1d7be83_0 and ipywidgets=8.1.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0. Hopefully this helps for the next person with the same problem.
